# Constructor executing more than once

Tags: apex, soql

I am stuck and not able to find out why it is not working.
My constructor is getting executed 5 times which is creating problem for me.

```
<apex:page Controller="PrtnerMonthlyReport" sidebar="true" renderAs="pdf" action="{!saveAttachmentInDocument}" >
<!--   some code..... -->
</apex:page>
```

My class method is:

```
public void saveAttachmentInDocument(){
       Blob b;
       String reportName=Monthandyear+'-'+'Partner Mothly Report';               
       Document doc= new Document();
       if([select id,name from Document where FolderId='00lN0000000f8YB' and name like :reportName].size() == 0){          
       PageReference pdf = Page.PartnerMonthlyReport;
       pdf.setRedirect(true);
       if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
            b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('AA=='); // zero-length, null-terminated string
       } else {
              try {
                b = pdf.getContent();
              } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        if(b!= null && exec == true ){
            doc.FolderId='00lN0000000f8YB';
            doc.name=Monthandyear+'-'+'Partner Mothly Report';            //set the report name
            doc.body=b;
            insert doc;
            exec=false;                              
        }                                                    
             }    
         }
```

Note:Ignore the folderId which i have taken to just test the flow.

Here is my constructor:

```
public PrtnerMonthlyReport() {      
        //Initialize the values to zero.
        System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
        cumulDisbursement=0;cumulRepayment=0;cumulOutstanding=0;                         
        axisBankBalance=0;dbsBankBalance=0;lenderRepaymentBalance=0;totalBankBalance=0;                                 
        repaymentCollected=0;prinicpalPaid=0;interestPaid=0;expectedRepayment=0;
        disbursementLoanTranche=0;serviceFeeLoanTranche=0;repaymentRate=0;calculatePercent=0;
        overallTotalBalance=0;
        Month=System.Today();                       //Get the current month
        datobj=system.today();
        dy = datobj.day();
        mon = (datobj.month());
        yr = datobj.year();
        Monthandyear=String.valueof(dy)+'-'+String.valueof(mon)+'-'+String.valueof(yr);
        //Query from Partner__c object and find the sum of Total_Amount_Disbursed__c,Total_Principal_Paid__c and Total_Out_Standing__c for the particular month.
        For(Partner__c partner : [SELECT Total_Amount_Disbursed__c,Total_Principal_Paid__c,Total_Out_Standing__c FROM Partner__c WHERE Company__c='a0L9000000JfjmM'  limit 50000]){
            cumulDisbursement=cumulDisbursement+partner.Total_Amount_Disbursed__c;
            cumulRepayment=cumulRepayment+partner.Total_Principal_Paid__c;
            cumulOutstanding=cumulOutstanding+partner.Total_Out_Standing__c;
        }
        //Query from Cumulative_Data__c object and find the sum of Axis_Bank_Balance__c,DBS_Bank_Balance__c and Lender_Repayments__c for the particular month.
        For(Cumulative_Data__c cumData : [SELECT Axis_Bank_Balance__c,DBS_Bank_Balance__c,Lender_Repayments__c FROM Cumulative_Data__c WHERE Id='a0L9000000JfjmM' LIMIT 1]){
            if(cumData.Axis_Bank_Balance__c != null){
                axisBankBalance=cumData.Axis_Bank_Balance__c;
            }
            if(cumData.DBS_Bank_Balance__c != null) {
                dbsBankBalance=cumData.DBS_Bank_Balance__c;
            }
            if(cumData.Lender_Repayments__c != null){
                lenderRepaymentBalance=cumData.Lender_Repayments__c;
            }
                totalBankBalance=totalBankBalance+axisBankBalance+dbsBankBalance;    //Calculate the total available bank balance.
        } 
        //Query from Loan_Tranche__c object and find the sum of Service_Fee__c and Amount_Disbursed__c for the particular month.
        For(Loan_Tranche__c ltranche : [SELECT Service_Fee__c,Amount_Disbursed__c FROM Loan_Tranche__c WHERE (Loan_Tranche__c.Date_of_Disbursal__c = THIS_MONTH )AND(Loan_Tranche__c.Lender__c='KVVS') LIMIT 50000]) {
            disbursementLoanTranche=disbursementLoanTranche+ltranche.Amount_Disbursed__c;
            serviceFeeLoanTranche=serviceFeeLoanTranche+ltranche.Service_Fee__c;
        }
        //Query from Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c object and find the sum of Repayment_Amount_Received__c,Principal_Paid__c,Interest_Paid__c and Total_Principal_Expected__c for the particular month.
        For(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c pmrepay : [SELECT Repayment_Amount_Received__c,Principal_Paid__c,Interest_Paid__c,Total_Principal_Expected__c FROM Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c WHERE(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Repayment_Received_Date__c = THIS_MONTH)AND(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Lender__c='KVVS') LIMIT 50000]){
            if(pmrepay.Repayment_Amount_Received__c != null){
                repaymentCollected=repaymentCollected+pmrepay.Repayment_Amount_Received__c;
            }
            prinicpalPaid=prinicpalPaid+pmrepay.Principal_Paid__c;
            interestPaid=interestPaid+pmrepay.Interest_Paid__c;
            //calculatePercent=calculatePercent+pmrepay.Total_Principal_Expected__c;
        }  
        For(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c pmrepayThisMonth : [SELECT Repayment_Amount_Received__c,Principal_Paid__c,Interest_Paid__c,Total_Principal_Expected__c FROM Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c WHERE(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Expected_Repayment_Date__c = THIS_MONTH)AND(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Lender__c='KVVS') LIMIT 50000]){
            if(pmrepayThisMonth.Total_Principal_Expected__c != null){
            calculatePercent=calculatePercent+pmrepayThisMonth.Total_Principal_Expected__c;
            }
            }
        For(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c pmrepayNextMonth : [SELECT Total_Principal_Expected__c FROM Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c WHERE (Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Expected_Repayment_Date__c = NEXT_MONTH)AND(Partner_Monthly_Repayment__c.Lender__c='KVVS' ) LIMIT 50000]) {
            if(pmrepayNextMonth.Total_Principal_Expected__c != null){
                expectedRepayment=expectedRepayment+pmrepayNextMonth.Total_Principal_Expected__c;
            }
        }  
        try{     
            repaymentRate=prinicpalPaid/calculatePercent*100;
        }catch(MathException me)
        {
            System.debug(''+me);
        }
        //Calculate the overall available balance.Total=Bank Balance+Expected repayment- Lender Repayment
        overallTotalBalance=(totalBankBalance+expectedRepayment)-lenderRepaymentBalance;     
 }
```

Note:Please ignore the hardcoded id's.
My major concern is the method because i am saving the pdf in document folder and there should be only one copy of the report which will get saved every month.
My getters method:

```
public String getMonth() {
        return Monthandyear;
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getCumulDisbursement() {
        return cumulDisbursement.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method

    public Decimal getCumulRepayment() {
        return cumulRepayment.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getCumulOutstanding() {
        return cumulOutstanding.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getAxisBankBalance() {
        return axisBankBalance.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getDbsBankBalance() {
        return dbsBankBalance.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getLenderRepaymentBalance() {
        return lenderRepaymentBalance.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getTotalBankBalance() {
        return totalBankBalance.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getRepaymentCollected() {
        return repaymentCollected.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
     public Decimal getPrinicpalPaid() {
        return prinicpalPaid.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
     public Decimal getInterestPaid() {
        return interestPaid.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
     public Decimal getExpectedRepayment() {
        return expectedRepayment.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getOverallTotalBalance() {
        return overallTotalBalance.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getDisbursementLoanTranche() {
        return disbursementLoanTranche;
    }//End of getter method
     public Decimal getServiceFeeLoanTranche() {
        return  serviceFeeLoanTranche.setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
    public Decimal getRepaymentRate() {
        return repaymentRate.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }//End of getter method
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code of your constructor?

Comment: Hi FrankZ i have shared the constructor code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your constructor gets called 5 times is because you are creating an infinite loop with this code.

When u visit your "PartnerMonthlyReport" page for the first time, your constructor gets called (new controller is created for this page). After that your page is created, your method "saveAttachmentInDocument" gets called. So far no loop.

The method "saveAttachmentInDocument" does however create the loop since here you create a new "PartnerMonthlyReport" page, this way a new page and controller are created. And again like before you call the same method which creates a new page and so on and so on.

Best way to solve this is by using 2 seperate pages. One page which, after loading, calls a the 2nd page which will do the rendering of your data. This way the 2nd page doesn't have to call the method "saveAttachmentInDocument" and your loop will be resolved.

Hope this can help you further.